# protect secrets in flutter app from reverse engineering

Tags: android, flutter, dart, environment-variables, reverse-engineering

I started developing on an existing flutter application and see that they have used regular .dart files to keep the api and secrets. This is of course in the .gitignore file, but I was wondering what will happen when the application is bundled and released. If somebody does reverse engineer the application, wouldn't those files be visible then?

I was thinking of using .env file and this library [flutter_env package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_dotenv) instead. Will this be a better solution or is it all the same if the application is reverse engineered?

Answer (score 0):

> The client is in the hands of the enemy.

Yes, you can make it dead easy, or a little harder, to get to the things in the client. But generally, expect *everything* stored in client code or on the client device to be compromised sooner or later.

So if said secret should not be known to the client's user, don't save it on the client. At all.